# Problem using html5/js Audio with Safari (Windows)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

I'm trying to add sound to my html5 game, strangely in Safari i get this error in the js console: "Result of expression 'Audio' [undefined] is not a constructor".

I'm using the following code to load the sounds:

```
var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = "audio/click" + soundext;
sound.onLoad = ResourceLoad();
```

I would appreciate any help with solving this problem!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old, but it's what turned up when I searched for the problem, so for the benefit of other searchers, here's the answer I found, from http://infobrink.com/safari-not-liking-the-html5-audio/

> After much frustration I came across a post which indicated that HTML5
>   audio and video tags will not work in Safari without QuickTime. So
>   much for HTML5 not requiring any plug-ins. I installed QuickTime and
>   to my dismay Safari was now giving me the following error when I tried
>   to start it up.

Turns our QuickTime was not correctly installed!