# How come Audio does not play in Safari and gives me an error ''undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio()')'

Tags: javascript, audio

Please find my code below that works on IE,Firefox and Chome.How come it does not work in Safari? It gives me an error **'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio()')**

```
var playSound = function (){
    var audio = new Audio(),
        audioFileName = 'click',
        canPlayOgg = !!audio.canPlayType && audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"') != "",
        ext = (canPlayOgg)?'.ogg':'.mp3';

    audio.setAttribute("src",audioFileName + ext);
    audio.play();
}
<input type="button" onclick="playSound();"/>
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572478/problem-using-html5-js-audio-with-safari-windows

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you forgot a semicolon at the end of your var/constructor lines and that causes it? E.g., try

```
var audio = new Audio(),
    audioFileName = 'click',
    canPlayOgg = !!audio.canPlayType && audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"') != "",
    ext = (canPlayOgg)?'.ogg':'.mp3';
```

Comment: No mate thats not the issue,just corrected it but same result.cheers

Comment: What version of Safari on what OS are you using? Especially some windows versions were sometimes tricky to deal with. It could help to have a condition in advance, e.g. ('Audio' in window) ? new Audio() (I've also seen new Audio(''))

Comment: Christian Burtchen thanks for ur answer,but got it working after I installed Quicktime